# Does uuid v1 have browser compatibility issues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, uuid, compatibility

I checked the information and learned that uuid version1 is generated based on timestamp and MAC address. Is there any browser compatibility problem? For example, some browsers cannot obtain the MAC address.

I'm now using an npm package called `uuid` in a javaScript project.

I am using the v4 version now, but there is a possibility of duplication, and I hope that a version of the uuid generation algorithm can be replaced.

This is my code:

```js
import { v1 as uuidv1 } from 'uuid'; 
const uuid = () => {
  return uuidv1()
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Obtaining the MAC address from a browser? I don't think that's possible at all.

Comment: I'm quite sure (and strongly hope), the JS engine within the browser is not able to read my MAC adress ...

Comment: What does that have in common with a browser?

Comment: Understood, thank you, I will check the implementation of uuid v1 npm package. It may not be a combination of timestamp and MAC address.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I am a beginner, and I thought of this question when I was looking up information. I learned that the uuid v1 algorithm is generated by timestamp and MAC address, so I am considering whether there is any browser compatibility problem.

Comment: Well, it'll either produce an error, or substitute the unavailable MAC with something else. In either case, you should define what you *want*. Just any random UUID? Then you want a v4 anyway. If you do want system-specific UUIDs… that's either not possible in a browser, or you need to define better the why and what.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, but the scenario I encountered with V4 may be repeated, because the amount of my data is huge. Through other answers I learned that I can use v1 in all browsers.

Comment: The chance that *any* UUID will ever be repeated is… *tiiiiiiiiny.* Is this really a problem?

Comment: @deceze I was just thinking that the pseudorandom numbers might repeat when the data size is large.

Comment: [*"For example, the number of random version-4 UUIDs which need to be generated in order to have a 50% probability of at least one collision is 2.71 quintillion .. This number is equivalent to generating 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years. A file containing this many UUIDs, at 16 bytes per UUID, would be about 45 exabytes."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions)

Comment: @deceze It turns out that I have too little knowledge, I should learn more, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. It's not possible to read a system's interface mac address from a browser. At least not with the standard API. That would be a privacy nightmare.

Check the implementation of `uuid` (or whatever package you intend to use) and you'll see they won't be using a MAC address for their version 1 UUIDs - simply because it's not possible to obtain such information from a browser.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) states that:

> Version-1 UUIDs are generated from a time and a node ID **(usually the MAC address)**

(emphasis mine)

So the node ID is *usually* a mac address. Although wikipedia is not the authoritative source for generating UUIDs I think we can safely assume that's the case (with the node ID being usually the mac address).

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/blob/main/src/v1.js#L25) code of `uuid` package:

```
  // node and clockseq need to be initialized to random values if they're not
  // specified.  We do this lazily to minimize issues related to insufficient
  // system entropy.  See #189
  if (node == null || clockseq == null) {
    const seedBytes = options.random || (options.rng || rng)();

    if (node == null) {
      // Per 4.5, create and 48-bit node id, (47 random bits + multicast bit = 1)
      node = _nodeId = [
        seedBytes[0] | 0x01,
        seedBytes[1],
        seedBytes[2],
        seedBytes[3],
        seedBytes[4],
        seedBytes[5],
      ];
    }

  // later in the source code ...

  // `node`
  for (let n = 0; n < 6; ++n) {
    b[i + n] = node[n];
  }
```

We can see that `uuid` package simply uses a random value for the mac address instead.

Comment: Thanks! I learned that in this case, I use the v1 generation algorithm to have a lower probability of repetition than the v4 generation algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I learned a lot!